# Untrusted Source .jar file will not open

Tags: 15.10

How could I bypass blocked files from "untrusted" sources? I am using 15.10 (Wily Werewolf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give it the executable bit.

Run this command in terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo chmod +x yourfle.jar
```

Then you can run it normally with:

```
java -jar yourfile.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Type in the terminal:

```
sudo chmod +x file.jar
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Why would you post the exact same answer that I did?

Comment: I didn't! I just knew the answer to the problem. I typed my answer. Posted it, the page refreshed and then I saw your post. I didn't mean to copy you.

Comment: Understood. Although a banner should have popped up that said "A new answer has been posted" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Although the terminal version already posted is easier for completeness sake, you can also right click the .jar in a file explorer go to Permissions and select allow executing file as program.

[image: Image of checkbox]

Comment: If you include a screenshot with the option circled in red, I'll +1.

Comment: @AndroidDev sorry I was at work when I answered. Added a screenshot.